# What is correct GRUB_GFXMODE variable format in grub?

Tags: grub2

What is the correct format for the `GRUB_GFXMODE` variable in `/etc/default/grub`?

Should it have a dash before the color depth?...

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1200-24
```

Or, should it use an "x" before the color depth?...

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1200x32
```

Also, should the color depth be "`32`" or "`24`" ?

Comment: It should be an "x". You can use any valid number, I doubt you will notice any difference between 24 and 32 bit in grub or the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is to use an `x`:

```
widthxheightxdepth
```

Interestingly, at the top of the file it mention a command to get help with this file :)

```
info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
```

This command will give you the following information at *15.1.10*:

[image: screenshoot]

There is also [web documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#gfxmode) in HTML format.

About the depth value, as long as it is an integer you'd be fine :-)

Comment: I did review the info file, but didn't see that.  Thanks for finding this and posting the image and documentation link!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! BTW, I don't blame you about that, the resolution section was down under, a *lot* of scrolling to reach it :)